Vanishing of Chern characters implying vanishing of Chern classes?
Suppose that $X$ is a complex manifold and $E$ a holomorphic vector bundle. If I know that the Chern characters $ch_k(E)$ are zero for every $k > 0$, then can I conclude that the Chern classes $c_k(E)$ are also zero? Also since the first term of $ch_k(E)$ is the rank of the bundle does $ch_k(E) = 0$ even hold true ever?

As you noted, $\operatorname{ch}_0(E) = \operatorname{rk}(E)$, so this only vanishes if $E = 0$ (or if you allow sheaves, this can happen if the support of $E$ is not all of $X$). Also note that if all $c_k(E) \in H^{2k}(X,\mathbb Z)$ are torsion, then $\operatorname{ch}_k(E) = 0$ for all $k>0$, because $\operatorname{ch}$ is defined using rational coefficients.
But in $H^*(X, \mathbb Q)$ your question has a positive answer: If you think of the Chern classes as elementary symmetric polynomials in the Chern roots, then the $\operatorname{ch}_k(E)$ are the power sums of the Chern roots. Since the ring of symmetric polynomials over $\mathbb Q$ is generated by both the elementary symmetric polynomials and by the power sums, vanishing of one type implies vanishing of the other (i.e. you can express the $c_k$ in terms of the $\operatorname{ch}_k$ and vice versa).

So considering these in $H^*(X, \Bbb R)$ it is safe to say that $ch_k(E) = 0 \implies c_k(E) = 0$ for $k > 0$? @red_trumpet

@Nikolai If this holds for all $k$, yes.
